# Geolocation and IP address targeting for ads

Tags: geolocation, ip, adsense, google-ads-api, geotargetting

I'm trying to create a Ad campaign with either or both Google Adwords and Google Analytics. The key point for the campaign is to target a specific geographic location and a specific range of class 4 IP addresses and no one else.

I would like the ability to rotate between ads once a specific IP address has already seen an ad in the Ad group.

I've seen something like this done by a company called We-Care-Software and when you click on the image in the email they send it takes you to a landing page for a Time Warner Cable or Verizon Wireless promotion.

I'd like to do something similar to that but targeting IP address ranges. I want to know if this is possible with Google Adsense, DoubleClick for Publishers or Adwords even because with the research I've been doing I haven't come across anything so specific with their services, only geographic targeting, but I need to go deeper than that. Maybe there is an alternative web app that does this?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do this directly with any Google products as far as I am aware.  This is due to privacy as IP address targeting (even ranges) could be considered as personally identifiable information.  There is IP exclusion, but you can only exclude up to 500 entries, and although wildcards are supported, they are only for the last byte of the address.

If you have a website (e.g. are you a publisher?) that the users are likely to see, you can do the bucketing on your own server (e.g. "BucketA" for users in range 255.255.x.x, "BucketB" for users in range 255.254.x.x etc etc), and the dynamically fire off an [adwords remarketing tag](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/) with the appropriate bucket ID.  You can then target the ad groups to the different buckets in AdWords without Google having to target the IP ranges (as it is targeting the buckets you told it about instead).  This approach obviously wont work with users who have not been to your site yet though.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. So what you're saying is, I need to specify a number of IPs (referred to as buckets) for users in specific ranges, and if a user from a specific bucket visits the site show them specific ads from Adwords? So the server would communicate with Google Adwords through remarketing and show a user with an IP in that range a specific ad when they are searching on Google? Not sure if I got that right.

Comment: You'd be looking to group users into buckets - e.g. say I visited your site with IP 255.255.0.1, you'd fire an adwords tag with a custom parameter of "BucketA".  If someone else came with 255.254.0.1, fire it with "BucketB" etc.  If someone came with 255.200.0.1, don't fire anyting.  This way you're grouping users into remarketing segments, which allows you to do custom targeting in AdWords.  Note that you'll need several hundred users in each segment before they are usable for targeting.

Comment: I get the concept now. This could work definitely for Adwords, and I'll definitely research this method more, though the idea would be to also use Adsense ads that would appear on other websites and targeted at those specific IP ranges. That is also what I'm aiming for. Thoughts?

Comment: Well if you target your ad groups appropriately in AdWords (e.g. one ad to target the bucket a audience list, another to bucket b etc) then Google will do the rest with regards to showing ads only to the right people

Comment: Ok, so next to the remarketing tag, would this require some custom Javascript integrations or is it just having a list of IP addresses or range in a .txt file hosted on our server?

Comment: You'd need some javascript to work out if the visitor's IP address is in a range of interest, then update the tag's parameters as required.

Comment: Is it only limited to Javascript? Could i possibly use PHP to detect if the visitors IP address is in a specific range and then echo the correct Remarketing tag parameters in a global header file?

Comment: Or is it better suited with Javascript?

Comment: Well you can do it in a number of ways - server-side or client-side - whichever you are most comfortable with really.  The most important thing though is that you will need to use some javascript to update the AdWords remarketing tag to include the bucket parameter - there are some details & examples here (scroll down and click on the Dynamic AdWords Remarketing Tag tab): https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/